# Circular animation speeds up after running a while

Tags: javascript, typescript

I hope you can help me out here as I have meet my nemesis... Math!

I am making a background animation that will run constantly and it works fine exept one litle thing, it speeds up by a tiny amount over a very long time.

I have extracted the code that is essential for the script.

The animation is simple, it creates a bunch of circles that it then move around in a circular motion for ever. faster/slower and bigger/smaller randomly on creation.

**So if the animation runs for let's say 40min~ the circular animation will have increased it's speed A LOT!**

The constructor is run about 100 times and the instances is put in a particles array, here i just set the default values when instantiating the circles

```
constructor(){
   this.radius = 100;
   this.xPos = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.width);
   this.yPos = Math.round(Math.random() * canvas.height);
   this.counter = 0;
   this.maxWidth = 14;
   this.width = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.maxWidth - 4) + 4); //4 -> 24
   this.speed = Math.random() * 0.4; //0.0 -> 0.4
   this.color = "#3cccd3";
   this.alpha = this.getAlpha();

   this.sign = Math.round(Math.random()) * 2 - 1;
 }
```

The draw method is run in the animation loop, I have checked many examples on animating a circular motion and this seems to be the popular way to do it, but there animation dont speed up as mine do :)

```
draw() {
  this.counter += this.sign * this.speed;

  ctx.beginPath();
  //define the circleparticle
  ctx.arc(this.xPos + this.radius * Math.cos(this.counter / 100) ,
        this.yPos + this.radius * Math.sin(this.counter / 100) ,
        this.width,
        0,
        Math.PI * 2,
        true);


  ctx.globalAlpha = this.alpha;
  ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
  ctx.fill();
}
```

And this is just the loop

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //empty the canvas
    particles.forEach((particle) => particle.draw()); //run the draw method

    if(playParticles && !gameFocus) {
      requestAnimationFrame(draw); //rerun
    }
}
```

**UPDATE HERE IS THE FIX**

In the constructor

```
this.speed = 100 + Math.random() * 500;
```

In the draw method

```
this.timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now());
this.counter = this.sign * (this.timestamp / this.speed * Math.PI);
```

Comment: Show where you alter speed please.

Comment: The counter variable is incremental, that is what is making a circular motion. 

The sign varible is just if its a posetive or negative value making it go either clockwise or anticlockwise

and the speed varible says how fast that circle should go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not find anything in your code to explain a continuous increase in rotation speed.

However, the speed of your animation is a product of how often the draw method is called. You increment the counter a fixed amount for each invocation, but there is no guarantee that it will be called at any given frequency.

`requestAnimationFrame` will call your draw function each time it is ready for a new rendering. The timing of it could vary depending on a number of things, such as the time you need for each draw, the total computational load of your webpage, the total CPU load of your device or its power settings.

Instead of making the counter be a product of the draw methods call count, consider making it a product of time. For this reason, the first argument to the callback of `requestAnimationFrame` is a timestamp which should be used as the current time in each part of that rendering.

**Edit: example code**

The code below is a simplified example, producing x and y which together describe a circular motion of one revolution per second.

```
requestAnimationFrame(
    function(timestamp) {
        var counter = timestamp / 1000 * Math.PI;
        var x = Math.cos(counter);
        var y = Math.sin(counter);
        // do something with x and y
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks Alvin for your suggestion, they way I understood `requestAnimationFrame` was that it was the most reliable method when making animations and make incremental values.

Could you make a example on what you are suggesting. ( does not have to be directly with my code )

Comment: Your code suggestion seems to work, it is no longer spinning out of control :) Thanks